# Break on exception even with exception handling middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following middleware in my ASP.NET Core application:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    // Constructor and other stuff...

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "An unhandled exception was thrown!");

            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception and return a human-readable
        // message in a JSON-object in the response...
    }
}
```

Which I add to the pipeline in the Startup.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
```

When running the application from Visual Studio the debugger doesn't break when an exception happens, but is just handled in the middleware and execution continues. However, I want the debugger to break at the place the exception is thrown, when it's not caught by anything but this middleware. **How do I achieve this?**

I actually tried not adding this middleware when running locally. E.g. doing the following in Startup.cs:

```
// I'm setting env to "none" when running locally
if (!env.IsEnvironment("none"))
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
}
```

But this seems to just cause the frontend to act differently - understandably as it's not receiving a readable JSON-object, but it makes me think the problem is not my middleware. I'd prefer to keep this middleware active but if that's not possible while getting the debugger to break properly I guess I can live with that.

Comment: You should be able to "step back" in VS, if not, just comment out the try/cach and it should break on the actual error.

Comment: Sure, but right now it requires that I manually put a breakpoint in this middleware, as the debugger is not automatically breaking. If I remember correctly in ASP.NET there's a method in Global.asax which let's you handle exceptions globally but still allows the debugger to behave properly by breaking at the place the exception is thrown

Comment: @Jite also commenting out those lines just gives the same behaviour as not attaching the middleware. The debugger still doesn't break

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Kahbazi could you please expand on what you're referring to with this link? Configuring exceptions to "break when thrown" means the debugger will break even if I have a catch-clause to catch it. I'm not interested in this.